# Unable to reach a service endpoint from a pod deployed in a GKE cluster to another pod within the same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm encountering an issue with network communication between pods in my Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster. I have two pods within the same cluster, and I'm trying to make HTTP requests from one pod to a service endpoint hosted by another pod, but I'm consistently getting connection errors.

Here's a summary of my setup:

GKE Cluster: I have a Kubernetes cluster running on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using Google Kubernetes Engine.
Pods: I have two pods deployed within the same namespace.
Service: I've created a Kubernetes Service to expose one of the pods. The service is of type ClusterIP.
Networking: Both pods can resolve each other's DNS names, and I can successfully reach one of the pods using its IP address.
However, when I try to make HTTP requests from one pod to the Service endpoint (e.g., http://service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local), I consistently receive connection errors like timeouts or "connection refused."

Here is the yaml for the container with loadBalancer service running :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dashboard-deployment
spec:
   replicas: 3
   selector:
     matchLabels:
        app: dashboard
   template:
    metadata:
     labels:
      app: dashboard
    spec:
     containers:
       - name: <name of the image>
         image: <docker image name>
         ports:
          - containerPort: 8501
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dashboard-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: dashboard
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80 # port where the service is listening
      targetPort: 8501  # port where the pods are listening
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The yaml for the clusterIP type service which has the port 5000 exposed :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inference-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inference
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inference
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <docker image>
        image: <docker image name>
       ports:
       - containerPort: 5000  # Port for Flask app
          name: http-port
        env:
        - name: WANDB_API_KEY
          value: WANDB_API_KEY_VALUE
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inference
spec:
  selector:
    app: inference
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80  # Port for Flask app
      targetPort: 5000
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what might be causing this problem. Is there something specific I should be checking within GKE, or is there a common issue I might be overlooking?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the service endpooints i have tried are :  `http://inference.namespace.svc.cluster.local:5000`
 `http://inference:5000`

Comment: correction : the service endpooints i have tried are :  `http://inference.default.svc.cluster.local:5000`
 `http://inference:5000`

Comment: Are you using the default namespace(called default)? Did you try http://inference.default.svc.cluster.local ?

Comment: It's also helpful to show us the output of 'kubectl get pods' in your namespace.

Comment: @jsxqf yeah i have tried that

Comment: @jsxqf here the the output from `kubectl get pods`
kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dashboard-deployment-9f8f5fcf9-j2pbt    1/1     Running   0          37m
dashboard-deployment-9f8f5fcf9-mh7rb    1/1     Running   0          37m
dashboard-deployment-9f8f5fcf9-sqrc5    1/1     Running   0          31m
inference-67df446bdd-jw8r6   1/1     Running   0          31m
inference-67df446bdd-ql6px   1/1     Running   0          33m
inference-67df446bdd-sx72j   1/1     Running   0          33m

Comment: i guess the problem here is the port on the inference containers are not reachable , i have checked the dockerfile and it looks good as i have exposed the port in that container , but still the port is not reachable

Comment: Finally able to figue out the problem: the flask application that was deployed was not listening to otehr network interfaces, had to provide this in the app code : `flask.run(host='0.0.0.0', port:5000)` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try once `http://inference.namespace.svc.cluster.local:80`

you are exposing port **80** of **service** :**inference** but traffic to connect over **5000**

**TargetPort** you have mapped correctly to the **container port** **5000**, but in service **port** is the one which you use for connecting not **targetPort**

In your case, `http://inference.namespace.svc.cluster.local` will work as Port is **80** which is default so

Comment: i have tried with 80 as well as 5000 but it didn't work, i have even tried `curl -I <other pod's ip addr>:5000` from the load balancer's pod but it doesn't work

Comment: what is status of PODs did you checked app running inside it ? you exec and check once flask app running as you have not added readiness liveness probes

Comment: yeah the app is runninig i have checked:
`curl -I localhost:5000/home
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.3.7 Python/3.10.5
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 11:36:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
Content-Length: 13
Connection: close

Comment: Ohh any firewall or network policy set on a cluster which is blocking PODs communication ?

Comment: i have created this cluster from the console with default settings

Comment: there is a setting called `Shielded GKE nodes` which is Enabled , do you know what is this about ?

Comment: no that's for node and security purposes won't be blocking the traffic between pods

Comment: checked network policy ?

Comment: i see no network policy defined : `$ kubectl describe networkpolicy
No resources found in default namespace.
$ kubectl get networkpolicy
No resources found in default namespace.`